# How to write to a text file that is publicly available to other apps on Android device?

Tags: android

If my Android app has a `targetSdk` of 31, how can I write to a text file that is publicly available outside of my app by other apps, such as the built-in "Files" system app?

Previously I was writing to a file in the device's public Documents folder using `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)`, but this method is deprecated and when I use it after changing the `targetSdk` from 28 to 31 I get the error `MediaProvider: Permission to access file: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/my_log.txt is denied`.

I'm happy to write to my application-specific Documents folder, e.g. `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.company/files/Documents/my_log.txt`, but how can I make this publicly visible/available to the Files app? `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()` no longer works for this.

Is there a solution that doesn't require a user interaction such as a "Save as..." flow?

Comment: You could try putting it in `Downloads/` or `Documents/`, either via `MediaStore` or filesystem APIs. Other ordinary apps will not have access to it, but file managers and other apps with `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` should.